# Estimating the series: $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{k^a b^k}{k!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, estimation

Any idea on how to estimate the following series:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{k^a b^k}{k!}$$

where $a$ and $b$ are constant values. 
Greatly appreciate any respond.

Comment: a and b are supposed to be integers, or just fixed real numbers?

Comment: fixed real numbers.

Comment: Well, you could see it like a power series of the variable b, and if you call f the function, you get :

$\frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!} = \frac{k^a}{k!}$ => $f^{k}(0) = k^a$

Comment: the power of f is the k-th differentiation of f

Comment: What @mvggz seems to hint at: If $a$ is a nonnegative integer, this is just $(x\,\mathrm{d}/\mathrm{d}x)^a(\exp x)$ at $x=b$.

Comment: got it Thanks! Although $a$ is not necessarily an integer.

Comment: Putting t = log(x) gives:

x d/dx = d/dt 

so, in case of fractional a, it's given by the a-th fractional derivative w.r.t. t

Comment: Sorry to ask this, but I'm having trouble understanding the meaning of the expression $(x\,\mathrm{d}/\mathrm{d}x)^a(\exp x)$ , the power "a" more precisely, what does it represent exactly in terms of operator (if it is one, which is what I'm assuming) ?

Comment: Actually it's ok, sorry for the trouble..

Comment: @mvggz: The $(\ )^a$ means iteration/nesting of the operator in the parentheses.

Comment: That's what I thought, thanks. But I was not going in that direction at all though :)

Comment: A [related question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/161068).

Comment: @Lucian thanks for your comment. That seems to be very close to what I'm trying to get at. The behavior of a function including this series. I'm going to ask a new question explaining the entire problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found a closed-form of this series, but I don't know how to prove it yet. I've asked for a proof in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/979902/153012).

Let $a \in \mathbb{N}$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}$. Then

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{k^a\,b^k}{k!} \stackrel{?}{=} e^b \sum_{j=0}^a S(a,a-j+1)\,b^{a-j+1},$$

where $e$ is [Euler's number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_%28mathematical_constant%29) and $S(n,k)$ are the [Stirling numbers of the second kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind), defined as

$$S(n,k) = \frac{1}{k!}\sum_{i=0}^k (-1)^{i}{k \choose i} (k-i)^n,$$

with ${n \choose k}$ a [binomial coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient).

Beside I don't know how to prove it, I also don't know how to generalize it to $a \in \mathbb{R}$, because I don't know about this type of generalization of the Stirling numbers of the second kind.

For now the best you could do to take the [floor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions) of $a$, and then using the closed-form. If you want to esimante there are good [lower and upper bounds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind#Lower_and_upper_bounds) for $S(n,k)$, and we have results about its [asymptotic behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind#Asymptotic_approximation).

Comment: Thanks This helped since I could use the bounds on Stirling number.

Answer (score 2):

If my calculation is correct, we have

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{k^a}{k!} x^{k} = e^{x} \left\{ x^{a} + \binom{a}{2}x^{a-1} + \mathcal{O}(x^{a-2}) \right\}$$

as $x \to \infty$. I have only an iPad currently in my hand, which is apparetly inadequate for $\TeX$ing. So I will elaborate my answer later.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this?

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose  $a > 0$ and $b > 0$.  If $g(k) = k^a b^k/k!$, then 
$$ \dfrac{g(k+1)}{g(k)} = \left(1 + \dfrac{1}{k} \right)^a \dfrac{b}{k+1} \to 0
\ \text{as}\ k \to \infty$$
Take $0 < r < 1$ and $K$ such that $\dfrac{g(k+1)}{g(k)} \le r$ for $k \ge K$.
Then 
$$ \sum_{k=0}^\infty \dfrac{k^a b^k}{k!} \le \sum_{k=0}^{K-1} \dfrac{k^a b^k}{k!}
+ \dfrac{K^a b^K}{K!} \sum_{j=0}^\infty r^j = \sum_{k=0}^{K-1} \dfrac{k^a b^k}{k!}
+ \dfrac{K^a b^K}{(1-r)\; K!}$$

Comment: Thanks for the responds however, I'm not able to proceed as it seems now I need to find $\kappa$ and $r$. I have no clue how to do so.

Comment: For example,  $(1+1/k)^a < 2$ for $k > 1/(2^{1/a}-1)$, and
 $b/(k+1) < r/2$ for $k \ge 2b/r$.